# Effect of deviations from a normal distribution on Wilcoxon signed-rank test

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

Which type of deviations from a normal distribution, skewness or heavy-tailedness,
appears to have a greater effect on the Wilcoxon signed-rank test? Why?

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth reading about the assumptions underlying the test, such as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test

Comment: Thank you but I couldn't realize anything from the assumptions that relate to the question.

Comment: The biggest clue is in *"$H_0$: difference between the pairs follows a symmetric distribution around zero"*

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the point now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wilcoxon test is non-parametric and does not require the samples to be normally distributed, unlike the t-test. The t-test is usually preferable since it is more efficient in a statistical sense, but because it is parametric its assumptions are not always fulfilled. Hence, the Wilcoxon test is very popular when the t-test cannot be used.